# When the script is restarted, another instance of the script may open by itself

Tags: autohotkey

As a result 3-4 identical scripts may hang in the tray, how can you fix this?
Here is the upper part of the script:

```
`SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  
#SingleInstance Force
#Persistent
#NoEnv
#InstallKeybdHook
#InstallMouseHook
SendMode Input
Process, Priority,,, A
SetBatchLines -1
SetKeyDelay, -1, -1
SetMouseDelay, -1, -1
SetControlDelay -1
SetWinDelay -1
ListLines Off
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 99000000
#HotkeyInterval 99000000
#KeyHistory 0
#MaxThreads 255
#include Lsleep.ahk 
#include SpeedUp DLL.ahk
DllCall("ntdll\ZwSetTimerResolution", "Int",5000, "Int",1, "Int*",MyCurrentTimerResolution)
`
```

Tried the #SingleInstance Ignore and Force value, no difference.

Comment: Why the Notepad++ tag?

Comment: This is my first time on this site

Comment: Yes, but why the Notepad++ tag. Please [edit] the question to explain.

Comment: See [Debugging a Script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Scripts.htm#debug). You can also add MsgBox, ToolTips, FileAppend and the like in an [OnExit Function](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/OnExit.htm#function) and in the auto-execute section to see how the script behaves before exiting and after restarting.